# how to generate pdf using blade view with tcpdf laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, tcpdf

I'm trying to create a pdf using laravel 5 and https://github.com/elibyy/laravel-tcpdf

i have a form of 20 pages writing in laravel blade when my client fill the form and click submit i want to generate pdf for him and save it

i try to do it like this in my controller

```
public function createPDF()
{
    $pdf = Input::get('pdf',null);
    $company = Input::get('company',null);
    $branch = Input::get('branch',null);
    $sub_branch = Input::get('sub_branch',null);
    $form_type = Input::get('form_type',null);
    $form_name = Input::get('form_name',null);
    $form_heb_name = Input::get('form_heb_name',null);
    $sig_path=FormsController::getSignature_file();

    $data=compact('company','branch','sub_branch','form_type','form_name','form_heb_name','sig_path');
    Input::flash();
    if ($pdf) 
        { 
            $pdf = new TCPDF();
            $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
            $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->writeHTML(view('forms.'.$company.'.'.$branch.'.'.$sub_branch.'.'.$form_type.'.'.$form_name, $data)->render());
            $filename = storage_path().'/forms_pdf/10006/26/4718326/'.$form_name.'.pdf';
            $pdf->output($filename, 'I');
            return redirect('forms');
        }
     return view('forms.'.$company.'.'.$branch.'.'.$sub_branch.'.'.$form_type.'.'.$form_name , $data);
}
```

bat its not working it's create 2 pdf page with All fields on top of each other

how to fix it?

**In addition, I want to save the pdf in a way it can not be edited file how can i do it?**

thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: not with tcpdf i used [link](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will try to give you a step by step answer (tested for laravel 5.1):

Before using it, be sure that you installed the TCPDF service provider correctly:

**Installing TCPDF service provider**

In composer.json, add this package:

```
"require": {
    "elibyy/laravel-tcpdf": "0.*"
}
```

Run *composer update*

in config/app.php add this service provider

```
'providers' => [
    //..
    Elibyy\TCPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
]
```

Run *php artisan vendor:publish* , that will generate config/laravel-tcpdf.php in your files

**Generate the pdf in your controller**

```
public function createPDF()
{
    [...]
    //get default settings from config/laravel-tcpdf.php
    $pdf_settings = \Config::get('laravel-tcpdf');

   $pdf = new \Elibyy\TCPDF\TCPdf($pdf_settings['page_orientation'], $pdf_settings['page_units'], $pdf_settings['page_format'], true, 'UTF-8', false);

   $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
        $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->writeHTML(view('forms.'.$company.'.'.$branch.'.'.$sub_branch.'.'.$form_type.'.'.$form_name, $data)->render());
        $filename = storage_path().'/forms_pdf/10006/26/4718326/'.$form_name.'.pdf';
        $pdf->output($filename, 'I');
        return redirect('forms');
    
}
```

Comment: Hello,

i have a issue for the filename of tcpdf on download, for example 'Héllo oumaya.pdf' i had 'Hllo_oumaya.pdf' first special char is empty , second the space is replaced ' ' by '_' ???

any help please ? :'( :'(