# Laravel 5.2.45 Tcpdf installation failed with php version 5.5.11

Tags: laravel-5, tcpdf, laravel-artisan, php-5.5

I need to generate a PDF using TDPDF with Laravel 5.2.45.
I used the following command (reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30499090/how-to-generate-pdf-using-blade-view-with-tcpdf-laravel-5)):

```
composer require elibyy/tcpdf-laravel
```

and received the following message:
[image]

Message: Your PHP version <5.5.11> does not satisfy that requirement.

Is there any other way to download TCPDF with Laravel if my PHP version do not satisfy the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my composer with following command

```
composer update
```

Then added the following line to my composer.json file

```
{
"require": {
    "elibyy/tcpdf-laravel": "5.4.*"
} }
```

Next added the service provider to config/app.php.

```
'providers' => [
//...
Elibyy\TCPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
]
//...
'aliases' => [
//...
'PDF' => Elibyy\TCPDF\Facades\TCPDF::class
]
```

and again run the following command

```
composer update
```

And then to my controller I added the following lines:

```
use PDF; // at the top of the file

PDF::SetTitle('Hello World');
PDF::AddPage();
PDF::Write(0, 'Hello World');
PDF::Output('hello_world.pdf');
```

Now I am able to generate a PDF.